# How to get width and height of text not the span with display table-cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to find width and height of a text not the `span's` having `display:table-cell`. In side of a `div` with `display:table`.

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 50px; height: 343.559px;"><span class="nodeText" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-overflow: ellipsis;font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;color: black;opacity: 1;">Desktop 1.43k (53.34%)</span></div>
```

**Text width and height is**

**width is approx 45px

height is approx 35px**

Comment: u mean text measuring in pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the height of the span to be the height of the div (you want the space that the actual text takes up) you can extra wrap the text:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span>span");
console.log(
  span.getBoundingClientRect()
)
```

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 50px; height: 343.559px;">
  <span class="nodeText" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-overflow: ellipsis;font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;color: black;opacity: 1;">
    <span>Desktop 1.43k (53.34%)</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
var $e = document.getElementById("e");
var $a = document.getElementById("a");
// Thses are for the span itself...
// Only inner width and padding
console.log($e.clientWidth,$e.clientHeight);
// also scrollbar if presented and ...
console.log($e.offsetWidth,$e.offsetHeight);
// get the width after any computing necessary
console.log( $e.getBoundingClientRect() );
var style = window.getComputedStyle( $e );
console.log( style.font );

// Now combine them to measure string in pixels
var $canvas= document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = $canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = style.font;
var txt = $e.innerText;
var measures = ctx.measureText(txt);
console.log( ctx.font );
console.log( measures );
$a.style.height = Math.ceil(measures.width / $e.clientWidth) 
                       * parseInt(style.lineHeight) + 'px';
```

```css
div, #e { position:relative; }
#a { display:block;width:3px;background:red; }
```

```html
<!-- changed the size to fit in preview -->
<div style="display: table; width: 50px; height: 47px;"><span id="e" class="nodeText" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-overflow: ellipsis;font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;color: black;opacity: 1;">Desktop 1.43k (53.34%)</span>
<span style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
  <span id="a"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That will result in height of 343 and does not fit what the OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

Strange nobody recommended **getBoundingClientRect**:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/1ghaa42f/)

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0],
        rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
span.parentNode.nextElementSibling.textContent = "width: " + (rect.width|0) 
+ "\nheight: " + (rect.height|0);
```

PS: I see that you meant the client area without the padding. And  that was not clear in your question. Use 2 spans so that you end up with client areas.

[HERE - **width: 40 height: 32**](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/1ghaa42f/1/)

Comment: That will result in height of 343 and does not fit what the OP expected.

Comment: Because the OP did not realize the definition of client window in HTML. To do what he wants he can use 2 spans. In my PS is a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check for the `div` if it has a `display:table` then you can iterate through it and find the `span` with `display:table-cell` property.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach(div => {
    if(div.style.display === 'table'){
      let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
      spans.forEach(spn => {
        if(spn.style.display === 'table-cell'){
          let theSpan = spn.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(theSpan.width, theSpan.height);
        }
      });
    }
})
```